# Get Users location on Cocoa-touch

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am trying to get the users Lat and Long from GPS data on iphone.

here is my code:

```
//
//  SendLocView.m
//  AMR App
//
//  Created by Fletcher on 07/04/2016.
//  Copyright © 2016 LaserCamel Programing. All rights reserved.
//

#import "SendLocView.h"
@import CoreLocation;

@interface SendLocView ()

@end

@implementation SendLocView



- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    // Check for iOS 8. Without this guard the code will crash with "unknown selector" on iOS 7.
    if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
        [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    }
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/
- (IBAction)location_send:(id)sender {
    [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    NSString *Globalusername = @"1111";
    float latitude = locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude;
    float longitude = locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude;

    NSLog(@"Value of username is %@", Globalusername);
    NSLog(@"Value of latitude is %f", latitude);
    NSLog(@"Value of longitude is %f", longitude);


    NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"lat=%f&long=%f&username=%@",latitude,longitude,Globalusername];
    NSLog(@"PostData: %@",post);

    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.webaddress.org.uk/mobile/jsontracking.php"];

    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];




}


- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    NSLog(@"%@", [locations lastObject]);
}

- (void)requestAlwaysAuthorization
{
    CLAuthorizationStatus status = [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus];

    // If the status is denied or only granted for when in use, display an alert
    if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse || status == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied) {
        NSString *title;
        title = (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied) ? @"Location services are off" : @"Background location is not enabled";
        NSString *message = @"To use background location you must turn on 'Always' in the Location Services Settings";

        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title
                                                            message:message
                                                           delegate:self
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:@"Settings", nil];
        [alertView show];
    }
    // The user has not enabled any location services. Request background authorization.
    else if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {
        [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    }
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        // Send the user to the Settings for this app
        NSURL *settingsURL = [NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:settingsURL];
    }
}

@end
```

My Current output from NSLog(@"Value of latitude is %f", latitude); is

```
2016-04-08 21:54:29.170 AMR App[1394:467604] Value of latitude is 0.000000
```

But the NSLog(@"%@", [locations lastObject]); output is

```
2016-04-08 21:55:38.186 AMR App[1394:467604] <+51.50483880,-3.16954134> +/- 65.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 08/04/2016, 21:55:38 British Summer Time
```

any help as to why this is happening would be great

Comment: Most likely `locationManager.location` is nil, indicating that a location has not yet been received.

Comment: There are a few things that don't make sense; You are requesting `whenInUseAuthorization`, but then later you are requesting `alwaysAuthorization` - Which do you want? You are also calling `startUpdatingLocation` without waiting for the delegate callback to tell you the authorisation status has changed.  Finally, you have to wait to get a location in `didUpdateLocations` before you can access the `location` property.  You should check the property isn't nil in the `@IBAction` method

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for `CLLocationManager` states that it resolves location information asynchronously, meaning that you cannot make any assumptions about what might be available to you at any given time.

The AppleDoc discussion for `-startUpdatingLocation` explains why the values are nil in the first log message:

> This method returns immediately. Calling this method causes the
>   location manager to obtain an initial location fix (which may take
>   several seconds) and notify your delegate by calling its
>   locationManager:didUpdateLocations: method.

So, you should not expect to have any valid location information until the `-locationManager:didUpdateLocations:` delegate method is called. Based on the timestamps in your log message, it's clear that the location took about 1 second longer to resolve, which is actually in line with the documented timeframe from Apple engineering.

Note: the docs also suggest implementing the failure method...

> In addition to your delegate object implementing the
>   locationManager:didUpdateLocations: method, it should also implement
>   the locationManager:didFailWithError: method to respond to potential
>   errors.